# Rails: When the "flash" hash becomes empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

On `index` page of `MyController` I set a value to `flash[:notice]`:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    flash[:notice] = "my message"
    ...
  end
end
```

I do see `"my message"` displayed as expected.

However, when I click a link on this page that points to `index` page of `MyOtherController`, I still see `"my message"`:

```
class MyOtherController < ApplicationController
  def index
    puts "----------------------------------------"
    puts flash[:notice]    # => "my message"
    puts "----------------------------------------"
  end
end
```

I thought that `flash[:notice]` becomes empty with every request, but here this is not the case. What is the correct way to empty `flash[:notice]` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use `flash.now[:notice] = ...` instead. `flash.now` is useful when you dont want the flash message to persist to the next request. Often a `redirect_to` follows a `flash[:notice] = ...` which is why it is persisted for one request

Comment: So, when I use only `flash[:notice]`, when does it become empty ? Sometimes it becomes empty, sometimes not. Could you please elaborate on this ?

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time this rule should be correct:

Use `flash[:notice]` with `redirect`

Use `flash.now[:notice]` with `render`

Comment: So `flash[:notice]` before `redirect` and same before `render`?

Comment: I think he meant `flash.now[:notice]` with `render`.